# Error with simple session/cookie "Cannot modify header information"

Tags: php, session-cookies, setcookie

I tried transferring a working login system from one domain to another. It works perfectly on domain A, but starts giving errors:

> Warning: Cannot modify header
>   information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/hootlute/public_html/personal/example/files/admin/config.php:9)
>   in
>   /home/hootlute/public_html/personal/example/files/admin/admin_process.php
>   on line 34
>
> Warning: mysql_free_result(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL result
>   resource in
>   /home/hootlute/public_html/personal/example/files/admin/admin_process.php
>   on line 48

Below is my code from admin_process

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if ($_POST['adminID']=="") {
    $_SESSION['error']="Please log in with an admin account.";
    header('Location: http://login.example.com/login/admin');
}

include 'config.php';
include 'functions.php';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='" .$_POST["adminID"]. "' AND password='" .$_POST["password"]. "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);


// CHECKS FOR EXISTING ACCOUNT
if ($num_rows === 0) {
    $_SESSION['error']="Unable to log in. Admin account not found";
    printf("<script>location.href='http://login.example.com.com/login/'</script>");

}
else {
    $admin_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $cookie_info = $admin_rows['admin_id']."$".$admin_rows['name'];
    $expire = time() + 9800;
    setcookie("FS_admin_id",$cookie_info,$expire);
    $sql = "UPDATE admin set login_time = UTC_TIMESTAMP()  WHERE username='" .$_POST["adminID"]. "' AND password='" .$_POST["password"]. "'";
    $logresult = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$logresult) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }


    /* printf("<script>location.href='admin_home.php'</script>"); */

}

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_free_result($logresult);
mysql_close($conn);



?>
```

Line 34 = setcookie("FS_admin_id",$cookie_info,$expire);

What is wrong with the code? Is it because of the difference in PHP version ? 
I also get the same type of errors when I declare session_start() in the middle of my codes... despite not having any data printed.

I've been searching for setcookie() problems but the results were all related to the usage of setcookie().

Any reply will be much appreciated :)

Comment: I take a wild guess and say the cause lies in line 9 of your config.php script.

Comment: Lol @ mario... Check line 9 in config.php :) I bet you have a trailing whitespace there.

Comment: You would have solved your problem faster when carefully reading the error message than posting the question here. Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection too. Google it if you do not know what it means. It's not clever to display SQL errors directly, you should log it somewhere rather than displaying it in public

Comment: @Shehi Thank you for the comment, it was certainly helpful unlike some other comment. I had quite a few trailing whitespace indeed. Funny thing though. Why does the same file work on Domain A but not on Domain B ? Is there a setting that I have to edit on php ?

Comment: You are most welcome! Maybe you actually DID NOT move files from one server to another, but instead uploaded your local copies to a new location? :) Maybe your local copies were messed up because of your Editor? Using Dreamweaver? :D To avoid this in future, just remove ALL final `?>` lines from your PHP scripts. PHP can live without them :)

Comment: 30 min and not a single close vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer here as well :D

Check line 9 in config.php :) I bet you have a trailing whitespace there.

EDIT:
To avoid this in future, just remove ALL final ?> lines from your PHP scripts. PHP can live without them :) And also heed Lekensteyn's advice re SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to find white spaces before
2. Try to find white spaces after ?>, delete them.
3. Delete any echo that you can be doing before the code that modify the headers.
4. **try to change the file encoding of your php file to "ANSI".**

good luck!