# how to remove Cannot send session cookie error completely

Tags: php, session-cookies

i have searched alot thru the web, but none of the solution solved my problem..and i still get this error
**Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started** 
 here is my code

```
<?php 
   ob_start();  
   session_start();

   $myusername = $_POST['username'];
   $mypassword = $_POST['password'];

   $myusername = stripslashes( $myusername );
   $mypassword = stripslashes( $mypassword );
   $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string( $myusername );
   $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string( $mypassword );

   $mypassword = md5( $mypassword );

   $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
   if( !$con ) {
       die('Error connecting to server :'.mysql_error());
   }
   mysql_select_db("user_login",$con);

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM user_info WHERE username='$myusername' && password='$mypassword'");
   if( !mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {
       //echo "<b><p>Wrong username or password.</p></b>";
       //echo "<br /><a href='http://localhost/simic/option.php?page=login'> 
       Go back to login page </a>";
       header('Location: option.php?page=attempt_to_login');
   } else {
       $_SESSION['access'] = 1;
       $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST[username];
       header('Location: option.php?page=online');
   }
   mysql_close( $con );

   ob_flush();
 ?>
```

so how can i solve this please ??? any help?

Comment: you have some text [whitespace] before <?php in your file

Comment: `session_start();` should be the first thing to start the script, move it to line 01

Comment: @jycr753 session_start() doesn't matter, its okay on line 2

Comment: `headers already sent by (output started` why is it so common to not include (or it seems, read) the rest of this error message - where it says _exactly_ where the problem is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error with simple session/cookie "Cannot modify header information"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147129/error-with-simple-session-cookie-cannot-modify-header-information)

Answer (score 1):

Some servers by default add content to the generated HTML, make sure that's not the case (check the generated source file in browser and see if there is anything that you wouldn't expect).

Also try removing the BOM header (if it's UTF-8 encoded) in the PHP file. It shouldn't be an issue, but it's always worth a try.

Removing the BOM header is different for every editor. For Notepad++ go to Encoding menu and make sure that "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM" is selected. If you're using Sublime Text 2 click File > Save with Encoding > UTF-8 (not UTF-8 with BOM).

Comment: thenx, but where do i remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your file has correct encoding. It should be UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have *something* outputting text to the browser "too early". The first byte of text sent, from whatever source, flushes all the HTTP header information out to the browser and prevents any more "header" type operations (such as sending a session cookie). There are many things that can send text to the browser unexpectedly early: whitespace before a `<?php`, an error message to the screen, a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark in a file, or just program output or HTML that's out of order (coming before the cookie code). Looking at the HTML page source in the browser (View > Page Source or the like), you might be able to see this text. If your page is UTF-8, switch the browser to some single byte encoding such as Latin-1 to flush a Byte Order Mark out of hiding. Once you've identified this text, the big job is to track down where it came from and fix it.